# rails / css : variable width text inputs

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, textinput

Is this possible? I have an input (just one line, not a text-field) for comments which currently has a set width of 200px. But Could I make this text input scale with the browser width? So if the browser was 500px the input would be small but it it was 2560px the input would be very wide? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS attribute `width` with a percentage, like `20%`. [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/XnQgp/).